# While loop, when it operates with "string" data, How to abort it with a specific word or letter?

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

I'm just a beginner, so please don't judge too hard.
I'm trying to understand, how I can stop a while loop, when it's working with strings? When it's just numbers, it's easy to tie it up with any non numerical symbol or any specific number (like 0); But whet it's a string, it different. Help me to understand please.
So below is a simple code. At first I've tried to use as evaluation some characters like

```
while(name1!='q'){
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Then I wrote additional array with one specific string, and made a comparison:

```
char abort_name[4]={"stop"};
 short abort=strcmp(name1,abort_name);
    while (abort!=0) {
```

Take a look at my code. I understand that it probably doesn't work because of this non printed \0 symbol at the end of any string, and because I'm comparing 2 arrays one with 10 symbols and another only with 4, but how can I bypass it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char name1[10];
    char abort_name[4]={"stop"}; //I'm trying to use a cancelling word, but it doesn't work

    printf("enter you name here /stop - to cancel/:   ");

    int check1=scanf("%s", name1);
    short abort=strcmp(name1,abort_name);
    while (abort!=0) {
        printf("value is: %d\r\n", check1);
        printf("\r\nname is: %s", name1);
        printf("\r\n\r\nenter you name here:   ");
        short check1=scanf("%s", name1);
        short abort=strcmp(name1,abort_name);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

upd:
Now I found the mistake, thank you all for your explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 while (abort!=0)
 {
   ...
   short abort=strcmp(name1,abort_name);
 }
```

You are *shadowing* the `abort` variable defined in the `main` routine just above the `while` statement: those are 2 separate variables, so your condition never changes.

Change that to:

```
abort=strcmp(name1,abort_name);
```

to assign the main `abort` variable.

(note that there's the same problem for `check1`)

Also note that:

```
char abort_name[4]={"stop"};
```

defines an *array* of 4 strings. Not what you want, you need:

```
const char abort_name[]="stop";
```

or

```
const char *abort_name="stop";
```

(let the compiler compute the size for you BTW, `4` isn't enough because of nul-terminator)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using fgets for input and a do/while loop to iterate until `quit` is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char name1[100];
    int match = 0;

    do {
        printf("enter you name here ( or quit):   ");
        fflush ( stdout);//printf has no \n
        if ( fgets ( name1, sizeof name1, stdin)) {//get a line
            if ( 0 != ( match = strcmp ( name1, "quit\n"))) {//compare to quit\n
                printf("\r\nname is: %s", name1);
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets problem\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( match);

    return 0;
}
```